# Python で while を使って配列の文字列を取り出す方法を教えてください

Tags: python, python3

Pythonを活用して、下記が行えるコードを教えてください。

`list = ["A", "B", "C"]` から `while` を使って以下の通り出力する方法。

```
A
B
C
```

下記コマンドだとシンプルですが、whileでもできると思うのですが、
創造力が足りずわかりません。

〈参考〉

```
for value in list:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

> while を使って

```py
lst = ["A", "B", "C"]
while lst:
    print(lst.pop(0))
```

※ この操作の後、`lst` は空(empty list)になりますので、`lst` を変更したくない場合はコピーして下さい。(shallow copy で構いません)

```py
lst = ["A", "B", "C"]
lst_copied = lst[:] # shallow copy
while lst_copied:
    print(lst_copied.pop(0))
```

Comment: まだ学習していない解決方法だったので、今後の参考になります。

Comment: 今後もpythonを学んで行きますので、引き続きご指導よろしくお願いいたします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

添字使う方法もあるけれど, 比較的シンプルにすると
(@metropolis さんの回答のように)`while lst`のような指定になると思います

以下は `pop(0)`よりも高速と思われる方法

```py
lst.reverse()
while lst:
    print(lst.pop())
```

動的配列で実装されてるはずなので, 最初の要素の取り出しが最も遅く 最終要素の取り出しが最も高速なため

> リストをキュー (queue) として使うことも可能です。この場合、最初に追加した要素を最初に取り出します ("first-in, first-out")。しかし、リストでは効率的にこの目的を達成することが出来ません。追加（append）や取り出し（pop）をリストの末尾に対して行うと速いのですが、挿入（insert）や取り出し（pop）をリストの先頭に対して行うと遅くなってしまいます（他の要素をひとつずつずらす必要があるからです）。

参考: (docs.python.org) [データ構造](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues)

非破壊で行うなら (シンプルではないようだけど)

```py
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
(dmy:= lst[:]).reverse()
while dmy:
    print(dmy.pop())
```

Comment: 色々な解決方法があり、人によって特徴が出るのかと思うと興味深いです。今後も勉強させていただければ助かります。回答ありがとうございました。